# Binding same element events jQuery 2 different files

Tags: jquery

I have 2 files, in each of them there is

```
$("ul li").hover(function() {
```

one ( js file 1 )  just adds a class and detects if the dropdown menu needs to open in different position depending on site width , another one ( js file 2 ) animates ( fadeIn/out )  , seems like the one that animates is canceling the other.

```
$(this).find('div.holder').first().css('display','none').stop().fadeIn(300,function(){

       $(this).css('display','block');

    });
```

If I hover very fast than my class is added, if slow , the animation starts but my class is not added.  How can I bind them if they are in 2 different files?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Writing `$("ul li").hover(function() {` just attaches another event listener. You can have many of those in diferrent files, no problem. Could you post the JS from your second file? Or ideally create a fiddle? Just concatenate the two scripts, it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you much , while making the fiddle I found the bug , it is fade/in out adding display:none, than my offset cant see hidden element thus it dont know if it needs to add class or not. Thank you!